# Forge Extension for VS Code

Tags: autodesk-forge

Is it possible to add an extension to the Forge VSCode Application or is this strictly a way to just navigate and view/peek in VSCode?

[Forge Extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFWLP.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about adding a custom *Forge Viewer* extension into the viewer used inside the *Visual Studio Code* extension, that is not possible today but it sounds like a cool idea. Feel free to submit a feature request: https://github.com/petrbroz/vscode-forge-tools/issues.